# How to strip column and combine?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df: 
   home_score  away_score
1         0.0         1.0
2         2.0         1.0
3         3.0         2.0
4         0.0         0.0
5         1.0         1.0
```

Expected result:

```
    score
--  -------
 0  0:1
 1  2:1
 2  2:1
 3  3:2
```

I am trying

```
df['home_score'] = df['home_score'].astype(str).str.replace('^.*(.\d)', '', regex=True)
```

to strip the score before combining columns but I am not getting anything..

Also, this code worked on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/37omnR/1) How do I figure out this to work in python?

Comment: This should work: `df['home_score'].astype(str).str.replace('(.\d+)$', '', regex=True)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your columns to int first to remove decimal part then cast to string before join them:

```
cols = ['home_score', 'away_score']
df['score'] = df[cols].astype(int).astype(str).apply(':'.join, axis=1)
print(df)

# Output:
   home_score  away_score score
1         0.0         1.0   0:1
2         2.0         1.0   2:1
3         3.0         2.0   3:2
4         0.0         0.0   0:0
5         1.0         1.0   1:1
```